Metodo no se traduce a SQL al momento de utlizanlo en otro metodo
Cordial saludo. En estos momentos estamos realizan un metodo que nos permita identificar que datos han sido ingresados a una tabla y cuales no. Debido a que para ello dentro de nuestra logica, debemos hacer un join buscamos que la tabla de datos con la cual se va a evaluar de que los datos existen, tenga valores unicos para que la consulta no presente errores de timeout. Teniendo esto presente, lo primero que hacemos es un metodo que nos entregue una tabla con valores unico en la cual hacemos un group by asi:
/// <summary>
    /// 2024-07-10: Agrupar los datos por equipo en la tabla de historico de llantas para obtener un solo registro
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Lista de equipos</returns>
    [HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Equipos/Unicos", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasEquiposUnicos")]
    public List<TemListaTextoString> GetLlantasSalidasEquiposUnicos()
    {
        try
        {
            var q = from a in context.LlanHistoria
                    group a by a.equipo into GrupoA
                    select new TemListaTextoString
                    {
                        TextoString = GrupoA.Key
                    };
            return q.ToList();
        }
        catch
        {
            // 2024-07-10: Utilizo esta excepción para no crear mas excesiones y con esta puedo mostrar informacion
            // en caso de errores.
            return ObrasMantenimientoExcepcion;
        }

    }

Luego de hacer este metodo, creamos el metodo en el cual lo invocaremos para hacer el join. Este seria el siguiente metodo:
/// <summary>
    /// 2024-07-09: Crear la tabla que permita tener un campo que permita idetificar los equipos a revisar llantas.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Tabla de equipos a revisar llantas</returns>
    [HttpGet("/Llantas/Mantenimientos/Equipos/Revisar", Name = "GetLlantasMantenimientosEquiposRevisar")]
    public List<TemGeneMttoPrevObras> GetLlantasMantenimientosEquiposRevisar()
    {
        try
        {
            var t = GetLlantasSalidasEquiposUnicos();
            var q = from a in context.GeneMttoPrev
                    // 2024-07-09: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla b1).
                    join b1 in t on
                            a.equipo
                        equals
                            b1.TextoString
                        into GrupoB
                    // 2024-07-09: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new TemGeneMttoPrevObras
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        codigo_mantenimiento = a.codigo_mantenimiento,
                        ciclo = a.ciclo,
                        frecuencia_Mantenimiento = a.frecuencia_Mantenimiento,
                        unidad_frecuencia = a.unidad_frecuencia,
                        fecha_estimada = a.fecha_estimada,
                        fecha_mantenimiento = a.fecha_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_estimado = a.horometro_estimado,
                        horometro_mantenimiento = a.horometro_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_final = a.horometro_final,
                        resultado_muestreo = a.resultado_muestreo,
                        emp = a.emp,
                        // 2024-07-08: Debido a que en la clase o mejor dicho en C# no esposible tener
                        // datos tipo DateTime como null, se procede a modificar el dato.
                        FechaInsert = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01),
                        // 2024-07-09: Para no crear una clase para este metodo se aprovecha uno ya creado pero
                        // se inhabilitan el campo Obra, el cual se calcula realmente en otro metodo.
                        Obra = "NoAplica",
                        // 2024-06-21: Se valida si hay registros en la tabla indicada.
                        Estado = b == null ? "NoAplica" : "Aplica"
                    };
            return q.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return TemGeneMttoPrevObrasExcepcion;
        }
    }

Procedemos a validar el metodo e identificamas que hace un salto a la zona catch de excepciones, debido a ello, buscamos profundizar un poco mas y realizamos un debug a dicho metodo encontrando el siguiente error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<GeneMttoPrev>()
    .LeftJoin(
        inner: __p_0
            .AsQueryable(), 
        outerKeySelector: a => a.equipo, 
        innerKeySelector: b1 => b1.TextoString, 
        resultSelector: (a, b) => new TemGeneMttoPrevObras{ 
            Registro = a.Registro, 
            equipo = a.equipo, 
            bodega = a.bodega, 
            codigo_mantenimiento = a.codigo_mantenimiento, 
            ciclo = a.ciclo, 
            frecuencia_Mantenimiento = a.frecuencia_Mantenimiento, 
            unidad_frecuencia = a.unidad_frecuencia, 
            fecha_estimada = a.fecha_estimada, 
            fecha_mantenimiento = a.fecha_mantenimiento, 
            horometro_estimado = a.horometro_estimado, 
            horometro_mantenimiento = a.horometro_mantenimiento, 
            horometro_final = a.horometro_final, 
            resultado_muestreo = a.resultado_muestreo, 
            emp = a.emp, 
            FechaInsert = new DateTime(
                1900, 
                1, 
                1
            ), 
            Obra = "NoAplica", 
            Estado = b == null ? "NoAplica" : "Aplica" 
        }
    )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

De esta forma se identifica que el codigo que estamos escribiendo en LinQ de C# no esta siendo traducido a SQL y por ello no se logra concretar correctamente la consulta.
Sospechamos que el error esta a la hora de llamar el metodo GetLlantasSalidasEquiposUnicos() en el metodo GetLlantasMantenimientosEquiposRevisar(), pensamos que es en el momento de hacer el join aqui:
join b1 in t on
                            a.equipo
                        equals
                            b1.TextoString
                        into GrupoB
                    // 2024-07-09: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()

Pero a pesar de ello, no vemos otra forma de hacerlo.
Hemos evaludo escribir la misma consulta de diferentes formas para ver si logramos que funcione, esta es otra forma de hacerlo pero sigue presentando el mismo error:
/// <summary>
    /// 2024-07-09: Crear la tabla que permita tener un campo que permita idetificar los equipos a revisar llantas.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Tabla de equipos a revisar llantas</returns>
    [HttpGet("/Llantas/Mantenimientos/Equipos/Revisar", Name = "GetLlantasMantenimientosEquiposRevisar")]
    public List<TemGeneMttoPrevObras> GetLlantasMantenimientosEquiposRevisar()
    {
        try
        {
            var t = GetLlantasHistoricoListaEquipos();
            var q = from a in context.GeneMttoPrev
                    // 2024-07-09: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla b1).
                    join b1 in t on new TemListaTextoString
                    {
                        TextoString = a.equipo
                    }
                    equals new TemListaTextoString
                    {
                        TextoString = b1.TextoString
                    }
                    into GrupoB
                    // 2024-07-09: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new TemGeneMttoPrevObras
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        codigo_mantenimiento = a.codigo_mantenimiento,
                        ciclo = a.ciclo,
                        frecuencia_Mantenimiento = a.frecuencia_Mantenimiento,
                        unidad_frecuencia = a.unidad_frecuencia,
                        fecha_estimada = a.fecha_estimada,
                        fecha_mantenimiento = a.fecha_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_estimado = a.horometro_estimado,
                        horometro_mantenimiento = a.horometro_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_final = a.horometro_final,
                        resultado_muestreo = a.resultado_muestreo,
                        emp = a.emp,
                        // 2024-07-08: Debido a que en la clase o mejor dicho en C# no esposible tener
                        // datos tipo DateTime como null, se procede a modificar el dato.
                        FechaInsert = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01),
                        // 2024-07-09: Para no crear una clase para este metodo se aprovecha uno ya creado pero
                        // se inhabilitan el campo Obra, el cual se calcula realmente en otro metodo.
                        Obra = "NoAplica",
                        // 2024-06-21: Se valida si hay registros en la tabla indicada.
                        Estado = b == null ? "NoAplica" : "Aplica"
                    };
            return q.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return TemGeneMttoPrevObrasExcepcion;
        }
    }

Lo importante de todo esto es identificar la causa de la falla y como es la forma correcta para poderlo hacer desde Linq, ya que nos ha gustado mucho trabajar desde el lado del cliente.
Agradecemos la ayuda que nos puedan brindar.

En tu primer código, prueba cambiar  public List<TemListaTextoString> GetLlantasSalidasEquiposUnicos() por public IQueryable<TemListaTextoString> GetLlantasSalidasEquiposUnicos() y en el return cambiar return q.ToList(); por return q;

Hola Yussef, gracias por la información. Luego de hacer los ajustes mencionados y probar, concontramos que la consulta se queda ejecutando largo tiempo y no entrega los datos. En Swagger nos preguntó tres veces si espreamos (wait) y a pesar de ello, no entrega la respuesta.

Volviste al error del TimeOut. Tú tienes una consulta que es simple (un select, un par de join y un group by) y por otro lado tienes una cantidad de registros considerable no es brutalmente grande, pero si son bastantes como para que ya den problemas. Todo me lleva a pensar que tu problema está en la base de datos ¿Tus tablas tienen indices, tienen pk, tienen fk??

Hola Yussef, la tabla tiene indices, tiene pk, pero aun no he implementado fk.

Continuamos sin poder identificar la novedad que impide que el codigo sea traducido a SQL, agradecemos la ayuda que nos puedan brindar.

Es que tu problema es otro, intentaré explicarlo por última vez: Las instrucciones Linq son código C# que se convierten en SQL y no todo código es posible convertirlo. Tú tienes un List que no es posible convertirlo, por eso debes usar IQueryable. Por otro lado, cuando usas IQueryable te da timeout esto ya no es problema de Linq es problema de tu base de datos que no está bien optimizada, porque tú tienes una consulta simple. Si la consulta fuera compleja (que no lo es) podrías tener un rango de acción para mejorarla, pero no es el caso.

Por otro lado, si existen algunos trucos para mejorar una consulta Linq, como usar AsNoTracking(). Otro truco es usar ToList en algunos puntos claves, este último depende mucho de cada caso y se hace casi a ensayo y error. Lo que hace esto es traer todos los datos de la base de datos y procesarlos en C#, lo cual en mi opinión siempre será más lento que una consulta SQL (en una bd bien seteada), porque la base de datos es un software altamente especializado en consultas. Si quieres hacer la prueba cambia from a in context.GeneMttoPrev por from a in context.GeneMttoPrev.ToList()

Por eso todos mis comentarios apuntan que pruebes la consulta directamente dentro del motor y ahí ver qué pasa, para evaluar porque es tan lenta. Y que finalmente cambies tu pregunta de una de Linq a una de SQL, por, así como está tu pregunta no se puede responder, no hay nada que hacer por nuestra parte.

Hola Yussef, acabo de hacer la consulta en Sql y se genera en 7 segundos.

Mas a favor de lo que dice Yussef.. entonces cual es la necesidad de hacerla en linq... igual 7 segundos es una consulta particularmente lenta, salvo que estemos hablando de millones y millones de registros y falten indices y claves....

Y si hay millones y millones de registros, usar linq no es una buena idea.. no siempre optimiza las cosas como corresponde...

Cual es el criterio para saber si un dato existe o no en la tabla? @GermanDavid

Hola Japv, la idea es enforcarnos solo en los datos obtenidos en el group by. Dicho Group By nos entrega una lista de vehiculos. Con dicha lista de vehiculos, vamos a la otra tabla a buscarlos para decir si aplica o no su revision. Ese seria el criterio.
